# How to write sum in combination of case

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

here is my code that uses hibernate expecting  some thing like this

```
SUM( CASE WHEN model.voter.age 
            between '"+18+"' and '"+25+"' 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 18ageCount


org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: 
     expecting IDENT, found '18' near line 1, column 325
```

I am tried with different combinations but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just eroor because of `18ageCount` this one only  and i rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

[Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions) in hibernate used in the `where` clause. To workaround you need to rewrite the query

```
select sum(1) from model.voter where age between 18 and 25
```